# How to work with Hive using .NET

Tags: .net, hive

My current application is written by .NET (F# to be specific), and my company wishes to migrate the data source to Hive.

Is there a way to work with Hive using .NET? How should the servers to be configured and what libraries are needed?

I've searched for a while and couldn't find detailed information about it. There seems to be HDInsight that may work, but we need to build our own cluster.

Yes, there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493866) on the site, but the solutions are not specific enough. For example, there is no information on how to configure the servers or how to generate Thrift code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to Hadoop/Hive from .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493866/how-to-connect-to-hadoop-hive-from-net)

Answer (score 1):

I work with C# and Hive.
I use Hortonworks ODBC with this connection string:

```
connectionString = $@"
    DRIVER={{Hortonworks Hive ODBC Driver}};
    Host={host};
    Port=10000;
    HiveServerType=2;
    AuthMech=2;
    UID={username};
    Schema=default;";
var conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
```

Then you just work with the interface. for example to execute some statement do:

```
var command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "ALTER SOME TABLE";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Could you provide some instructions on how to use it? What need to be downloaded and referenced? I couldn't find good documentations.

Comment: go to https://hortonworks.com/downloads/ and then "Hortonworks ODBC Driver for Apache Hive". download the windows 64-bit version and follow the installation guide. I am not familiar with F#.. but as I said it works for me with C#